# Loop through array of objects in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, chart.js, ejs

I've got a Node web app and recently started incorporating the ChartJS library for data viz.  Here's what I've got nested in a script tag on an EJS template page:

```
<script>
let playerStatChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Freshman', 'Sophomore', 'Junior', 'Senior'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Points',
            // Works
            data: [1,2,3,4],
            // Does not work and appears blank
            // One of these data lines is commented out, so there isn't a redundancy
            data: pointAvg,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(149,16,16, 0.4)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#000',
            hoverBorderWidth: 3,
            hoverBorderColor: '#000'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Points: <%= player.name %>",
            fontSize: 25
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to dynamically populate the values in the **data** are of the dataset rather than a pre-defined array containing [1, 2, 3, 4].  As you can see, I'm already dynamically populating the title of the chart as the player name by injecting the value with EJS.  Here's an example "player" object that I'm working with:

```
  author: { id: 5e939f988ced3e0428c8b521, username: 'test' },
  comments: [
    {
      author: [Object],
      _id: 5eb31d2ea285dbf1f3eb6d80,
      text: 'Threesus forever.',
      createdAt: 2020-05-06T20:25:18.332Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  _id: 5e94ac2d81fa5428b0323fc1,
  name: 'Naz Mitrou-Long',
  image: 'https://alchetron.com/cdn/naz-long-b96e0ac4-b460-4dd7-ab76-de54cccbd62-resize-750.jpeg',
  position: 'Guard',
  description: 'Threesus of Nazareth',
  __v: 6,
  weight: 218,
  dob: 1993-08-03T05:00:00.000Z,
  hometown: 'Mississauga, ON',
  country: 'Canada',
  height_feet: 6,
  height_inches: 4,
  season: [
    {
      year: '2012-2013',
      grade: 'Freshman',
      gp: 18,
      gs: 0,
      mpg: 6.9,
      fg: 0.348,
      tp: 0.278,
      ft: 1,
      rpg: 0.8,
      apg: 1,
      spg: 0.3,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 1.4
    },
    {
      year: '2013-2014',
      grade: 'Sophomore',
      gp: 36,
      gs: 7,
      mpg: 20.3,
      fg: 0.432,
      tp: 0.4,
      ft: 0.643,
      rpg: 1.6,
      apg: 1.1,
      spg: 0.2,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 7.1
    },
    {
      year: '2014-2015',
      grade: 'Junior',
      gp: 34,
      gs: 33,
      mpg: 27.5,
      fg: 0.449,
      tp: 0.391,
      ft: 0.755,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 2,
      spg: 0.8,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 10.1
    },
    {
      year: '2015-2016',
      grade: 'R. Senior',
      gp: 8,
      gs: 8,
      mpg: 31.6,
      fg: 0.425,
      tp: 0.291,
      ft: 0.6,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 1.9,
      spg: 0.6,
      bpg: 0.3,
      ppg: 12
    },
    {
      year: '2016-2017',
      grade: 'Senior',
      gp: 35,
      gs: 35,
      mpg: 33.3,
      fg: 0.473,
      tp: 0.384,
      ft: 0.795,
      rpg: 4.6,
      apg: 2.7,
      spg: 1.2,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 15.1
    }
  ]
```

How can I loop through each player's "season" values and dynamically populate the data for the chart similar to the chart title.  Below is an example that I've been playing around with that's also in the script tag ahead of the code shown above:

```
let player = "<%= player %>"
let pointAvg = []

player.season.forEach(function(season){
    pointAvg.push(season.ppg)
     })
```

However, when I use this code and set the data value as `pointAvg`, the chart displays blank with no values.  What am I missing here?

Comment: you can youse map to return those ppgs as decimal numbers in your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map through your object season array and return the ppg property. By using map you can avoid using the extra pointAvg array.

```js
const input = {
  _id: '5e94 ac2d81fa5428b0323fc1',
  name: 'Naz Mitrou-Long',
  image: 'https://alchetron.com/cdn/naz-long-b96e0ac4-b460-4dd7-ab76-de54cccbd62-resize-750.jpeg',
  position: 'Guard',
  description: 'Threesus of Nazareth',
  __v: 6,
  weight: 218,
  hometown: 'Mississauga, ON',
  country: 'Canada',
  height_feet: 6,
  height_inches: 4,
  season: [{
      year: '2012-2013',
      grade: 'Freshman',
      gp: 18,
      gs: 0,
      mpg: 6.9,
      fg: 0.348,
      tp: 0.278,
      ft: 1,
      rpg: 0.8,
      apg: 1,
      spg: 0.3,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 1.4
    },
    {
      year: '2013-2014',
      grade: 'Sophomore',
      gp: 36,
      gs: 7,
      mpg: 20.3,
      fg: 0.432,
      tp: 0.4,
      ft: 0.643,
      rpg: 1.6,
      apg: 1.1,
      spg: 0.2,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 7.1
    },
    {
      year: '2014-2015',
      grade: 'Junior',
      gp: 34,
      gs: 33,
      mpg: 27.5,
      fg: 0.449,
      tp: 0.391,
      ft: 0.755,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 2,
      spg: 0.8,
      bpg: 0.1,
      ppg: 10.1
    },
    {
      year: '2015-2016',
      grade: 'R. Senior',
      gp: 8,
      gs: 8,
      mpg: 31.6,
      fg: 0.425,
      tp: 0.291,
      ft: 0.6,
      rpg: 2.9,
      apg: 1.9,
      spg: 0.6,
      bpg: 0.3,
      ppg: 12
    },
    {
      year: '2016-2017',
      grade: 'Senior',
      gp: 35,
      gs: 35,
      mpg: 33.3,
      fg: 0.473,
      tp: 0.384,
      ft: 0.795,
      rpg: 4.6,
      apg: 2.7,
      spg: 1.2,
      bpg: 0,
      ppg: 15.1
    }
  ]
}

const result = input.season.map(({
  ppg
}) => ppg);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: How would I be able to access this from an EJS template?

Comment: how does your template look like and how do you usually get the data out of it?

Comment: the "playerStatChart" in the first section of code above is in my EJS template in a script tag at the bottom.  What I'm trying to do is leverage those PPG values in the "data" section of the chart.